# Is Tamil locale language possible?

Tags: iphone, localization, tamil

I have added a `ta.lproj` (Tamil localized project) for my app and created localized Tamil strings.

When I wanted to verify that the localized text are correct, I found out there is no way I can do so because iPhone language settings (under General > Languages) does not support Tamil.

But I have seen apps in App Store that has Tamil as a supported language.

Is it possible to localize an app for Tamil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Tamil locale language is not supported.

Did you mention here about [mtamil-i](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mtamil-i/id330328801?mt=8)? If so it was created by using images.

You should create your own custom keyboard then.

Comment: Thanks. The app only support English. I was hoping to see a Facebook with Tamil support!

Comment: Hmm..nice idea.. bt you should do lots of works on keyboard alone.

Comment: i think there is no api provided by fb in tamil

Answer (score 2):

Tamil as localizable language is not yet supported.

But it is available as Region format. When you set this, you would see the Calendar, currency symbols in tamil.